# Is there anyway to use a array to hold sizes to use within a for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use a array that hold the size of columns to be used within a for loop example: dim lastColumn (1 to 2) as integer
lastcolumn(1) = 16. etc
for j = 2 to lastColumn(i)

```
Dim lastColumn(1 To 2) As Integer
    lastColumn(1) = 16
    lastColumn(2) = 23

For i = 1 To 2

  mapSrc = dataPullSheets(i)
  mapDest = lasSheets(i)

 Set sht1 = source.Sheets(mapSrc)      'set sht1 and sht2 to the source and destination worksheets
 Set sht2 = dest.Sheets(mapDest)

 Set startCell = sht1.Range("B2")

'find last row and last column
 lastRow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row          'find the last row and last columns in the sht1
' lastColumn = sht1.Cells(startCell.Row, sht1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For k = 1 To lastColumn()   <-- problem here           'copy/ paste the columns
        For j = 2 To lastRow            ' for loop to loop through columns A

            sht2.Cells(j + 3, sheetColMap(i, k)) = sht1.Cells(j, dataPull(i, k))        'used to copy the columns from sht1 onto sht2

              sht2.Cells(j + 3, 1) = Right(sht1.Cells(j, 1), 11)  'retrieve the values in the cells

        Next j              'populate the time
            Next k          'populate the vaulues
                    Next i                           ' loop through the indexes
                        source.Close True
Else                                'used to prevent a error message from popping up when the user choose to cancel selecting a file

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim lastColumn(1 To 2) As Integer
    lastColumn(1) = 16
    lastColumn(2) = 23

For i = 1 To 2

    Dim lastDefinedColumn as Long
    lastDefinedColumn = lastColumn(i)

    .... 

    For k = 1 To lastDefinedColumn

        ...
```

Comment: great to hear @JAYLEWIS. and Welcome to SO.